# Lots of Memory and CPU being used on nothing

Tags: ram, cpu

I noticed over the last week or so my computer is using a lot of CPU and Memory when nothing is obviously running (even after rebooting).

With only my browser open it's using 20% CPU, 4.0 GB Memory (I have 16 GB) and 2.8 GB cache.

How can I figure out what is wrong? Thanks!

Specs:

LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Release:    12.04

Codename:   precise

Answer (score 0):

You can view detailed log of the processes and their resources consumption using `htop`.

Install it typing `sudo apt-get install htop` and to run it type `sudo htop`. That should let you know what is using your resources. Once you figure it out, try killing that process and see if that works; if that worked, uninstall that application package or replace it with equivalent.

PS: Try `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update` to upgrade your machine to latest version. That might fix many issues.

BR